# How can I create a regex expression that will match anything between two words?

Tags: regex

How can I create a regex expression that will match anything between given words and these two words may not be on same line.

For example: OBJECTIVES or RECEIVED--------------------------------------

---

-------------------------------------OFFICE SETUP or REMAINING

Comment: depends what you mean by anything between words, do you mean for example the . between Ex.OBJECTIVES would be classed as a match aswel?

Comment: Depends on what language you are using, as syntax for regexes matching across multiple lines varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the words that are before and after are Objectives and Office Setup then use

```
(?s)(?i)(?<=(objectives)).*(?=(office setup))
```

This will match anything between Objectives and Office Setup regardless as to whether they are on multiple lines

`(?s)` means that '.' will match new lines also allowing it to match multiline

`(?i)` makes the rest of the regex case insensitive there for (objectives) will match objectives, ObJectivES etc and the same for office setup

`(?<=(objectives))` Positive lookbehind for the word objectives

`.*` 0 or more characters

`(?=(office setup))` Postive lookahead for office setup

Comment: No worries dude just say if you want an explanation of it

Comment: please..i will really appreciate it

Comment: Glad to be of service my friend